# Haystack custom form fields not showing in template

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I want to add an extra field to `Haystack` form, but for some reason, the form output in template isn't working.

Instead of displaying extra field, I get some weird template with model select fields. All I want is a single `q` input and an extra field for `author`.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from haystack.forms import HighlightedSearchForm

class QuestionSearchForm(HighlightedSearchForm):
    author = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, required = False)
```

**views.py**

```
# Create your views here.
from haystack.generic_views import SearchView
from search.forms import QuestionSearchForm


class QuestionSearchView(SearchView):
    form_class = QuestionSearchForm
    template_name = 'search/search.html'
```

**search/search.html**

```
<form method="get" class="form-inline" action=".">
    <div>
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Najdi"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `template_name` should be `template` in your views.py.

Take a look at the default `class SearchView` on the [haystack Github page.](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/views.py)